# Assistance applying poorly packaged patches?

Tags: centos, software-installation, upgrade, java, tomcat

I manage a handful of servers running the various roles of a [Ahsay online backup solution](http://www.ahsay.com).

A few times a year the software is updated and I need to apply patches on my servers.

Annoyingly the patches are rather poorly packaged/distributed, so where one would like to have the servers installed/updated using yum everything is instead handled manually.

Installing the server the first time is rather simple, unpack the archive file to /usr/local and run install.sh (to create init-scripts and such).

After that however the management start to get annoying. To make setting changes and rebrand the server you make changes to startup-scripts and the actual xml-files that make up the server.

This in itself would be no big issue if it wasn't for the fact that every time a new patch is released it comes with the stock versions of these files and instructions to overwrite the customized ones.

Rewriting the files on every update on multiple server naturally is quite a hassle.

So I find myself proofreading most of the files in the patch, handpicking the ones I figure contain the actual updates and updating only those.

Now, it is not billions of files, just enough of them to be annoying. The latest patch:

```
# find . -type f
./webapps/rdr/jsp/lib/common.js
./webapps/rdr/WEB-INF/lib/rdr.jar
./webapps/rdr/WEB-INF/web.xml
./webapps/rdr/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
./webapps/obs/WEB-INF/lib/rdr.jar
./webapps/obs/WEB-INF/web.xml
./webapps/obs/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilObdX86.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilFbdX64.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilObdX64.so
./tomcat/lib/mail.jar
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilSosSp9.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilFbdX86.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilLinX64.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilLinSpc.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilSosX86.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilLinPpc.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilLinArm.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilLinP64.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilLinX86.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilSosX64.so
./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilSosSpc.so
./tomcat/lib/ani.jar
./bin/startup.sh
./bin/shutdown.sh
```

Doing the following I've managed to spot the text differences more easily:

```
for NEW in `find . | xargs file | grep text | sed 's/:.*$//' | xargs`
do
 OLD=`echo $NEW | sed 's!^\.!/usr/local/rdr!'`
 echo -e "$NEW \t\treplaces $OLD"
 diff $OLD $NEW
done
```

And in this latest patch there where no update (that I could identify) to any of the text files. Meaning I could just replace the **diff** with **rm $NEW**.

After that I ran a diff over all of the files instead of just the text files:

```
# for NEW in `find . -type f | xargs`; do OLD=`echo $NEW | sed 's!^\.!/usr/local/rdr!'`; diff $NEW $OLD; done
Binary files ./webapps/rdr/WEB-INF/lib/rdr.jar and /usr/local/rdr/webapps/rdr/WEB-INF/lib/rdr.jar differ
Binary files ./webapps/obs/WEB-INF/lib/rdr.jar and /usr/local/rdr/webapps/obs/WEB-INF/lib/rdr.jar differ
Binary files ./tomcat/lib/mail.jar and /usr/local/rdr/tomcat/lib/mail.jar differ
Binary files ./tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilSosX64.so and /usr/local/rdr/tomcat/lib/libFileSysUtilSosX64.so differ
Binary files ./tomcat/lib/ani.jar and /usr/local/rdr/tomcat/lib/ani.jar differ
```

Giving the list of the 5 (out of 25) I actually need to change.

This seems like the kind of headache package maintainers deal with all the time, is there some way to make the process less cumbersome?

My servers (if it make any difference) are running CentOS 6.5.

Comment: When updating a package, a package manager (like rpm) just remove the old version completely  and reinstall the new one. So package maintainers do not have this problem.

Comment: Obvious recommendation. Make your own packages for this software. Then you only need to install the rpm in multiple places, not apply the patches in multiple places (which sounds like a freaking nightmare, if that is what you are actually doing). Debian's `deb` format as of the 3.0 quilt source format has a nice clean way of handling patches on top of some pre-existing upstream code. I don't know about rpm - perhaps someone can comment.

Comment: Just to be clear, are these binary updates you are talking about?

Comment: Its much easier if you use version control, if you already know how to do that at least... Create one branch to track your vendor's unmodified version, then have another branch with your modifications. You can then trivially import  changes from your vendor (to the vendor branch) and then merge to your local version. Then you can deploy that however.

Comment: What would you say constitutes a binary update?

Comment: The list of 25 files is the patch, the instructions from the vendor state that I should replace those 25 files in the server.

My problem is that I have made changes to for example ./webapps/rdr/WEB-INF/web.xml. If I extract the patch archive into the server path the file get overwritten and those changes get lost.

What is extra annoying is that that file in particular is not updated since the last patch, or actually since the last major release, so there is no reason to overwrite it at all.

Comment: Then do as @derobert suggests, and create your own packages. Fedora has [instructions](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) on creating packages, it's [packaging guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines) are relevant to CentOS. Most should be mostly the same, but CentOS uses somewhat older tools, so there can be differences. Given that you get shipped the files to install, most of the configuring/building steps are redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your description, you don't get patches but rather updated versions of files. What you could do is to keep text files from a vanilla installation of your software in `~/sw_current` with a copy in `~/sw_new`. Every time you get an update, you should apply it to `~/sw_new` by blindly copying the files and generate a real `diff` patch:

```
diff -rupN ~/sw_current/ ~/sw_new/ > update.patch
```

That would produce the patch with instructions on which lines to update in which files, while keeping the rest of the files intact. This patch should then be applied to your real installations:

```
cd /path/to/software
patch < update.patch
```

Note that if you manually changed a particular text line on your system, and then that line got updated, applying the patch will produce a conflict that you will have to resolve manually.

Once the update have been applied, don't forget to remove your vanilla `~/sw_current` directory and copy the contents of `~/sw_new` to `~/sw_current`.

Concerning the binary files provided with updates, you can just copy those on all your machines overwriting the originals, as I imagine you never modify binary files.